# Do we need greater visibility of "Location"?

Tags: feature-request

I have been reading a few questions and it has occurred to me that there already a number of different answers depending on which country you live in. I can see many other potential questions on topics such as schooling, health care, legal matters, etc. that would have differing answers depending on the asker's country.

I think adding the askers location to their OP may help with this. This would just be on the  Parenting site.

Comment: It's also already caused some confusion with terminology.

Answer (score 4):

I don't expect that parenting.SE will be modified to show location information. Instead, we can focus on the content:

- For every question *where location is relevant,* ask the author to specify it.
- For every question *where the child's age is relevant,* ask the author to specify it.

Over time, we can hope that most questions will reflect location and/or age, and new users will see this and write their questions in a similar matter.

<sub>Sidenote/rant:

Perhaps it's just me, having lived in so many countries, but I have the impression that location is most often omitted by North-American users; the rest of the world is aware of the fact that the world is not just American, that there are other countries that might be completely different, that the *"world series"* should imply more than one or two countries. Oops, sorry. Please don't flame me.</sub>